# xmpp and facebook, cant get clear list of online users

Tags: facebook, chat, xmpp, c#

I using this [code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/JabberClient.aspx?msg=2887722) to connect to facebook chat. When I try to retrieve list of online users instead of user name I get negative number for example: -1479115148@chat.facebook.com

How can I get the original (Letters) user name?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query for user vcard-temp and that shall give you all the display information you need about -1479115148@chat.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

After you request the roster, iterate through all the elements and send a vcard request for each person. You will get a response with the full name and icon

```
<iq 
    id='v3'
    to='-1479115148@chat.facebook.com'
    type='get'>
  <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
</iq>
```